# The local server can't reach the statics files with app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-staticfiles

Im following the [Running Django on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) guide but [at the step](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#use_the_django_admin_console) where I can launch the local server using `python manage.py runserver` using the Google secret and proxy the local files are giving a 404 error. However, when I deploy the app it works perfectly.

I ran `manage.py collectstatic` and I try to modify the `app.yaml` but it didn't work.

this the structure of the project :

```
├── app.yaml
├── cloud-sql-proxy
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqllite3
├── home
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── main.py
├── manage.py
├── noxfile_config.py
├── README.md
├── requirements-test.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   └── home
├── templates
│   └── registration
```

and the home/static/ look like this

```
home/static
└── home
    ├── cgv.pdf
    ├── css
    ├── font
    ├── img
    ├── js
```

the `settings.py` contain :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
```

the static files are called like this in the template:

```
{% static /local/path/to/static/file %}
```

Comment: You don't have sample code showing how you're calling/loading your static files and the structure of your application directory (folders) so one can't help you. However, you should note that running your app on local env with ```python manage.py runserver``` bypasses your ```app.yaml``` file and that file usually contains instructions on how GAE should treat your static files. This could be why your static files works in Production but not on local i.e. you've correctly told GAE where to find your static files (in ```app.yaml```) but you haven't correctly told your local server

Comment: You added a comment that you tried to modify your ```app.yaml``` file. Since your app works in Production, you shouldn't modify your ```app.yaml``` file. The way you run your App locally won't use it. The only way to use the file when you run your App locally is to run your App with ```dev_appserver.py```